# Countability of the wobbling group of a bounded geometry metric space

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $(X, d)$ be a uniformly discrete metric space of bounded geometry, that is, $\sup_{x \in X} |B_r(x)| < \infty$ for every $r \geq 0$ and there is a uniform $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) \geq \delta$ for all $x \neq y \in X$.

Let $G$ be the so-called *wobbling group of $X$*, that is, the set of all bijections $f \colon X \rightarrow X$ such that

$$ \sup_{x \in X} d(x, f(x)) < \infty. $$

**Question:** is $G$ countable?

Comment: For $X=\mathbf{Z}$ it has continuum cardinal.

Comment: @Ycor Does it? I've been told otherwise. Do you have a proof of it?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to post an answer.

Comment: In $\mathbf{Z}$ just exchange any prescribed set of even numbers to their successor. Morality: never believe what you're told :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say that a metric space $X$ is *hyperdiscrete* if the distance map $X\times X\to\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$ is a proper map, i.e. for every $R$, the set of $(x,y)$ such that $d(x,y)\le R$ is finite. For instance, with the Euclidean distance, $\mathbf{N}$ is not hyperdiscrete, but the set $\{0,1,4,\dots\}$ of squares in $\mathbf{N}$ is hyperdiscrete. The terminology is from my book with P. de la Harpe, Example 3.A.14(7) ([ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3796), [EMS link](https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=209)).

Let $X$ be a proper discrete metric space (i.e., every bounded subset is finite— note this forces $X$ to be countable) and $W(X)$ its wobbling group (= permutations of $X$ at bounded distance to identity).

> **Proposition.** Equivalent statements:
>
> 1. $W(X)$ is countable
> 2. $W(X)$ has cardinal $<$ continuum
> 3. $W(X)$ is reduced to finitely supported permutations
> 4. $X$ is hyperdiscrete.

Suppose (4) fails. Then there exists an injective sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $d(x_n,x_0)$ tending to infinity, such that $d(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})$ bounded. Then there is an injective homomorphism from the group $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^\mathbf{N}$ into $W(X)$, mapping $(a_n)$ the permutation exchanging $x_{2n}\leftrightarrow x_{2n+1}$ whenever $a_n=1$, and identity elsewhere. So (2) fails. Hence (2) implies (4).

The implications (3)$\Rightarrow$(1)$\Rightarrow$(2) are trivial.

Finally, if $X$ is hyperdiscrete and $f$ is a permutation at distance $\le R$ to identity, then since $\{(x,y):d(x,y)\le R\}$ is finite, its projection to $X$ is finite, and $f$ has to be identity elsewhere, so $f$ is finitely supported. Hence (4) implies (3).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was wondering indeed that it should not be countable, glad to know for sure.